# Password RegExpression

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I have following requirements for the Password field 
"The password must contain least 1 out of 4 groups:  upper case, lower case, number, special character"
anyone please help

Comment: yes it must contain at least one upper case, lower case, number, special character or it contain more then one but must be one of the above group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[0-9]{1,})(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*()_\+\-={}\[\]\\:;"'<>,./]{1,}).{4,}$`

should do it. Explaination:

`^` start

`(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})` at least one upper

`(?=.*[a-z]{1,})` at least one lower

`(?=.*[0-9]{1,})` at least one digit

`(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*()_\+\-={}\[\]\\:;"'<>,./]{1,})` at least one of the mentioned chars

`.{4,}` min length 4

`$` end